# Ubuntu 22.04 suspend not working / screen remains black

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04, xorg, suspend

**Problem:**
When I put my PC in suspend mode, the screen stays black. I can hear the fans of the PC and I can even change the brightness of the keyboard.

**System Information:**
Memory:

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            23Gi       1,7Gi        18Gi       1,4Gi       3,2Gi        19Gi
Swap:           30Gi          0B        30Gi
```

Nvidia-smi:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.161.03   Driver Version: 470.161.03   CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   37C    P0    16W /  N/A |      5MiB /  5946MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2177      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Secure boot:**
disabled

**Logs after trieing to wake up from suspend:**

```
(WW) modeset(0): hotplug event: connector 236's link-state is BAD, tried resetting the current mode. You may be leftwith a black screen if this>
(II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "CSO", prod id 5650
(II) modeset(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
(II) modeset(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
(II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
(II) modeset(0): Modeline "2560x1600"x0.0  282.70  2560 2608 2640 2720  1600 1603 1609 1732 -hsync -vsync (103.9 kHz eP)
(EE) modeset(0): failed to set mode: Invalid argument
(WW) modeset(0): Failed to set the desired mode on connector eDP-1
```

Uname -a

```
Linux marco-Legion-S7-16IAH7 6.1.8-060108-generic #202301240742 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Jan 24 08:13:53 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Possible solution:**
I have tried every kernel as many other solutions suggested this because there should be a problem with the kernel. I also tried every Nvidia driver version and had no luck either. But most solutions suggested to run the 470 driver version.

Comment: You are not the only one. The same for me. I gave up a long time ago. Good luck!